# Dataframe with one date and three distinct values: how can I get the one in the middle?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataframe containing the daily number of downloads for two apps. However every day I have 3 different download numbers: paid downloads (the highest value), organic downloads (the smallest value) and others (the middle value).

They are not labeled, so the only thing I know is that I need to order those three values and get the one in the middle. The original dataset looks like this:

| id | date | downloads |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2018-01-05 | 2000 |
| 100 | 2018-01-05 | 45000 |
| 100 | 2018-01-05 | 44000 |
| 110 | 2018-01-05 | 3000 |
| 110 | 2018-01-05 | 7000 |
| 110 | 2019-01-05 | 8000 |
| 100 | 2018-01-06 | 9000 |
| 100 | 2019-01-06 | 77000 |
| 100 | 2020-01-06 | 75000 |
| 110 | 2018-01-06 | 1000 |
| 110 | 2019-01-06 | 6000 |
| 110 | 2020-01-06 | 9000 |

And the final result I need would look like this:

| id | date | downloads |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2018-01-05 | 44000 |
| 110 | 2018-01-05 | 7000 |
| 100 | 2018-01-06 | 75000 |
| 110 | 2018-01-06 | 6000 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` to take the second element with [`nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
df.groupby(['id', 'date'], as_index=False).nth(1)
```